# Oracle Identity Column cycling

Tags: oracle, cycle, identity-column

Can I define this IDENT_COL to start over from minimum value by the values of other column(s)?

i.e. If tx_ref is the same, then increase IDENT_COL.currentval by 1, else start from 1.

```
CREATE TABLE ogun_test(
    col_a       VARCHAR2(10),
    col_b       VARCHAR2(10),
    tx_ref      VARCHAR2(20),
    ident_col   NUMBER(*,0)
                            GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
)
```

Comment: I think you must use the trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an identity that cycles:

```
create table t (
  c1 int
    generated as identity
    start with 1 cycle maxvalue 2
    nocache,
  c2 int
);

insert into t values ( default, 0 );
insert into t values ( default, 0 );
insert into t values ( default, 0 );

select * from t;

C1     C2   
    1     0 
    2     0 
    1     0
```

But not in terms of other columns. So you'll have to use some other solution.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a point before I let it go and try something else :)